# Problem in executing two or more threads of the same type - Pthread C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I need to make a program using the pthreads C library to work with threads. The text of the task says:

> There is a corridor that has a single lane for two directions and
>   there are two types of employees who will cross the corridor to reach
>   the opposite side of it. There are type 1 employees who go from left
>   to right and type 2 employees who go from right to left. In this
>   corridor there is an attendant who cleans this corridor when no one
>   passes through it. When cleaning the corridor, the employees of both
>   sides wait for it to end, otherwise, if the corridor is occupied, the
>   employee says he cannot clean and go to sleep 1 second.

If in the execution of the program I wanted to model two or more employees of the same type passing through, in the sense that while an employee of type X is in the corridor, one or more additional employees of that type arrive and want to take advantage of the permission to pass already acquired for the first one, how could I do so?

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//global variables 
int c1, c2; //counters for imp1, imp2
pthread_mutex_t m1, m2;
sem_t corridor; 
double clean = 0.5;

//implementation thread attendant
void *attendant(void *arg){
    sleep(1); //rest 1 seconds
    if (c1 == 0 && c2 == 0) {
        sem_wait(&corridor);
        printf("I'm starting to clean up\n");
        sleep(clean);
        printf("I finished cleaning\n");
        sem_post(&corridor);
    } else {
       printf("I can't clean, the corridor is busy\n");
    }

    return NULL;
}


//thread employee type 1
void *emp1(void *arg) {
    printf("I'm the number %d of em1\n", c1);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m1); //beginning critical section
    c1++;                    //it increases to signal the presence of a thread of the same type that wants to enter the corridor
    if (c1 == 1){            //the thread is the only one in the corridor. Can pass
        printf ("I am the first of my group emp1\n");
        sem_wait(&corridor);  //takes possession of the corridor
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1); //allows other threads of the same type to pass in the corridor since it was the first in his group. End of critical section

    // invents "passage" function

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);  //beginning of the critical section. Once crossed the corridor, the variable c1 is modified. A mutex is used to avoid inconsistency
    c1--;
    if (c1 == 0) {
        printf("I am the last of my group emp1\n");
        sem_post(&corridor);
    } //if c1 == 0, it is the last thread imp1 and releases the corridor
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1); //end critical section
    return NULL;
}


//thread employee type 2 
void *emp2(void *arg){
    printf("I'm the number %d of emp2\n", c2);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m2); //beginning critical section
    c2++;                    //it increases to signal the presence of a thread of the same type that wants to enter the corridor
    if (c2 == 1) {           // the thread is the only one in the corridor. Can pass
        printf("I am the first of my group emp2\n");
        sem_wait(&corridor);  //takes possession of the corridor
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2); //allows other threads of the same type to pass in the corridor since it was the first in his group. End of critical sectionritica

    // invents "passage" function

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m2);  //beginning of the critical section. Once crossed the corridor, the variable c1 is modified. A mutex is used to avoid inconsistency
    c2--;
    if (c2 == 0){
        printf ("I am the last of my group emp2\n");
        sem_post(&corridor);
    }//if c1 == 0, it is the last thread imp1 and releases the corridor
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2); //end critical section
    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    //pthread_t emp1, emp2, attendant;
    pthread_t idt;
    int r; //var random to create thread emp1 or emp2
    int i; //index 

    //variable initialization
    c1 = c2 = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&m1, NULL); 
    pthread_mutex_init(&m2, NULL);
    sem_init(&corridor,0,1); 

    pthread_create(&idt, NULL, attendant, NULL); 
    while (i < 40){
        sleep(1);
        r = rand() % 2;
        if (r == 0) {
            printf("Employee creation 1\n");
            pthread_create(&idt,NULL,emp1,NULL);
        } else {
            printf("Employee creation 2\n");
            pthread_create(&idt,NULL,emp2,NULL);
        }
        i++;
        pthread_join(idt, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read carefully some [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) or book; you should use condition variables, not semaphores. Semaphores are for [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) and you have *one* process with *several* threads

Comment: Semaphores are as much for threads as for IPC, @BasileStarynkevitch.  Some implementations of semaphores even need special, non-default configuration to be shared by multiple processes.

Comment: With that said, however, it is unusual to use both semaphores and mutexes in the same task. They have a great deal of overlap in their features and characteristics, so it is typical to choose one or the other, not both.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant in my comment (which is *not* an answer, just a comment). But I am not a native English speaker. I actually meant "semaphores are *usually* for inter-process communication". Using semaphore with threads (on Linux) is possible, but not common

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Generalities***

In order to implement

> while an employee of type X is in the corridor, one or more additional
>   employees of that type arrive and want to take advantage of the
>   permission to pass already acquired for the first one

, you first need to make it possible for that situation even to arise.  At present, you never have more than one `emp1` or `emp2` thread (combined) at any given time, because you join each one before starting another.  I think for this simulation you want to implement a random delay between employees in addition to the random employee type, launch all the employee threads with those delays between, and then join them all only after they have *all* been launched.

Additionally, you have to implement some kind of timing for traversing the corridor that at least sometimes is longer than the delay between employees, else you are still unlikely to get one employee arriving while another is in the corridor.

With that done, you need to something that models the permission to pass, or perhaps more effectively, that models who is currently in the corridor.  Furthermore, you need to do so in a manner that allows threads to *block* until there's at least a chance that they can proceed.

Although semaphores can be used perfectly well for some thread synchronization problems, a situation requiring threads to take turns or to acquire ownership of some limited thing usually wants a shared variable representing the owned thing / turn, a mutex protecting access to that variable, and a condition variable assisting threads  in waiting for their opportunity to proceed.

---

***Implementation approach***

There are basically two things you need to track:

1. Which employee type currently owns the corridor (type 1, type 2, *or attendant*)

   ```
   enum { ATTENDANT, TYPE1, TYPE2 } corridor_owner;
   ```

   , and
2. How many employees are currently in the corridor.

   ```
   int corridor_occupancy;
   ```

Furthermore, all threads need to rely on the same mutex to protect access to those data

```
pthread_mutex_t corridor_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

and they will likewise need a common CV

```
pthread_cond_t corridor_cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

With that in place, here's a reasonably good way to approach the problem:

**When an employee (thread) of type 1 or 2 wants to enter the corridor**, they must follow this procedure:

1. Acquire the mutex.
2. Check whether the corridor is currently owned by a different employee type and is already occupied:

   - if so, wait on the CV, and upon returning from the wait, restart step (2);
   - if not, claim the corridor for its employee type (possibly redundantly) and increment the corridor occupancy count.
3. Release the mutex

Note that this permits multiple employees of the same type to proceed through the corridor at the same time.

**When the attendant wants to enter the corridor**, it follows a different procedure:

1. Acquire the mutex.
2. Check whether the corridor is currently owned by a different employee type and is already occupied:

   - if so, first release the mutex, then sleep for one second, then go back to step (1);
   - if not, claim the corridor for its employee type, increment the corridor occupancy count, and then release the mutex.

**When an employee of any type leaves the corridor**, it must

1. acquire the mutex
2. decrement the occupancy count
3. if the occupancy count is zero then wake all threads waiting on the CV
4. release the mutex

Additionally, when the attendant thread leaves the corridor, it should sleep for some amount of time, then loop back to try to clean again -- as you've currently implemented it, it cleans only once.  You also need to either implement some kind of signal to make the attendant thread stop, or else make it a daemon thread (and not attempt to join it).